# Applying compactness theorem to show a property of a theory $K$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

First of all, the statement that I'd like to prove is basically similar to the statement in these three links below:

1. [Prove there is no theory whose models are exactly the interpretations with finite domains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090146/prove-there-is-no-theory-whose-models-are-exactly-the-interpretations-with-finit)
2. [Compactness and axiomatisability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656078/compactness-and-axiomatisability?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [compactness model theory question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754788/compactness-model-theory-question?rq=1)

Let me write down what the statement that I want to prove: There is no theory $K$ whose models are exactly the interpretations with finite domains. In all of these three links, they use compactness theorem and they consider a wf
$$\varphi_n=\exists x_1\cdots\exists x_n\left(\bigwedge_{0<j<i\le n}x_i\ne x_j\right).$$

I kind of understand their proofs, but I do have a doubt about these proofs. Can I really consider the above wf in a general theory $K$? It seems like I can consider that wf when $K$ is a first-order theory with equality.

If I can't consider the above wf in a general theory $K$, how can I prove the statement? I'd like to have an idea how to show it, so a hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing an implicit or explicit assumption that $K$ is a first-order theory with equality? You can, for instance, find a set of sentences in **2nd order** arithmetic modeled exactly by the finite sets, so this doesn't hold in full generality (not to mention it's pretty rare to prove anything substantial about "theories" in total generality).

Comment: Well it is possible that I missed that assumption. But I found this statement in a section where the first-order theory with equality has not been introduced yet, that's why I had my doubts. 
Also, what do you mean by 2nd order arithmetic?

Comment: In the context of model theory, "theory" typically refers to a first-order theory unless specified otherwise (and first-order logic is typically taken to always include equality).

Comment: @VicRyan Second order arithmetic is like Peano Arithmetic, but you are allowed to quantify over predicates (or equivalently sets) as well as just numbers.